# Custom self registration page not working

Tags: apex, customer-portal, self-registration

I am using a self registration page for guest user sign up.It is showing this error 
Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted.As far as i think it is because of create portal user as it is not returning userid

```
global class SelfRegisterController {    

@TestVisible 
private static boolean isValidPassword(String password, String confirmPassword) {
    return password == confirmPassword;
}

@TestVisible 
private static boolean siteAsContainerEnabled(String communityUrl) {
    Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = new Auth.AuthConfiguration(communityUrl,'');
    return authConfig.isCommunityUsingSiteAsContainer();
}

@TestVisible 
private static void validatePassword(User u, String password, String confirmPassword) {
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        Site.validatePassword(u, password, confirmPassword);
    }
    return;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String selfRegister(String firstname ,String lastname, String email, String password, String confirmPassword, String accountId, String regConfirmUrl, String extraFields, String startUrl, Boolean includePassword) {
    Savepoint sp = null;
    try {
        System.debug('Start of comp :: ');
        sp = Database.setSavepoint();

        if (lastname == null || String.isEmpty(lastname)) {
            return Label.Site.lastname_is_required;
        }

        if (email == null || String.isEmpty(email)) {
            return Label.Site.email_is_required;
        }
        UserRole usr =[SELECT Id, Name, PortalRole, PortalType, PortalAccountId, ParentRoleId FROM UserRole limit 1];
        User u = new User();
        u.Username = email;
        u.put('Email',email);
        u.UserRoleId = usr.id;
        u.ContactId='0030r00000Jmc0TAAR';
        u.FirstName = firstname;
        u.LastName = lastname;
        //u.ProfileId='00e6g000000ZEtV';
        String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();
        System.debug('networkId:: ' + networkId);

        // If using site to host the community the user should not hit s1 after logging in from mobile.
        if(networkId != null && siteAsContainerEnabled(Network.getLoginUrl(networkId))) {
            u.put('UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI',true);
        }

        String nickname = ((firstname != null && firstname.length() > 0) ? firstname.substring(0,1) : '' ) + lastname.substring(0,1);
        nickname += String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger()).substring(1,7);
        u.put('CommunityNickname', nickname);

        if (extraFields != null) {
            List<Object> extraFieldsList = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(extraFields);        
            for (Object thisFieldObject : extraFieldsList) {
                Map<String,Object> thisField = (Map<String,Object>) thisFieldObject;
                Schema.SObjectField sof = Schema.SObjectType.User.fields.getMap().get((String) thisField.get('fieldPath'));
                u.put(sof, thisField.get('value'));
            }
        }
        System.debug('includePassword:: ' + includePassword);
        if (includePassword) {    
            if (!isValidPassword(password, confirmPassword)) {
                return Label.site.passwords_dont_match;
            }
            validatePassword(u, password, confirmPassword);
        }
        else {
            password = null;
        }

        // lastName is a required field on user, but if it isn't specified, we'll default it to the username
        System.debug('userId:: ' );
        system.debug('accountId'+accountId);
        Contact con = [select id,accountid,name from contact where accountid ='0010r00000ISTRdAAP'];
        system.debug('con'+con.AccountId);
        system.debug('userDetails'+u);
        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, con.AccountId, password);

        system.debug('userId'+userId);
        // create a fake userId for test.
        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            userId = 'fakeUserId';           
        }
        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(email, password, startUrl);
                system.debug('if blocks');
                if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    aura.redirect(lgn);
                }
            }
            else {
                ApexPages.PageReference confirmRef = new PageReference(regConfirmUrl);
                if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    aura.redirect(confirmRef);
                }

            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        return ex.getMessage();            
    }
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Map<String,Object>> getExtraFields(String extraFieldsFieldSet) { 
    List<Map<String,Object>> extraFields = new List<Map<String,Object>>();
    Schema.FieldSet fieldSet = Schema.SObjectType.User.fieldSets.getMap().get(extraFieldsFieldSet);
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        if (fieldSet != null) {
            for (Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldSet.getFields()) {
                Map<String, Object> fieldDetail = new Map<String, Object>();
                fieldDetail.put('dbRequired', f.getDBRequired());
                fieldDetail.put('fieldPath', f.getFieldPath());
                fieldDetail.put('label', f.getLabel());
                fieldDetail.put('required', f.getRequired());
                fieldDetail.put('type', f.getType());
                fieldDetail.put('value', '');   // client will populate
                extraFields.add(fieldDetail);
            }}}
    return extraFields;
}

@AuraEnabled
global static String setExperienceId(String expId) {
    // Return null if there is no error, else it will return the error message 
    try {
        if (expId != null) {
            Site.setExperienceId(expId);   
        }
        return null; 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();            
    }        
}
```

}

Any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check your email (or ask the sys admin to do so if you are not the admin). It will have the actual error message in it.

I think you are missing the ProfileId. When you create a user, you should define a ProfileId for an user by running a code

```
u.ProfileId = [ SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Partner Community User'];
```

Replace `Partner Community User` with the name of desired profile